# GroupBy then Select with conditional record addition

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am having LINQ query in which I have to response with a result set which is depending on inner field collection. I have done the thing via LINQ query then a foreach but I wanted to avoid foreach loop and do it somehow from group by

```cs
List<ResultModel> result = new List<ResultModel>();           
var tempResultSet = _context.MainRecordTable.Where(h => h.id)
    .Select(lev => new 
    {
        Contacts = (lev.basetable2 != null 
                            && lev.basetable2.basetable3 != null 
                            && lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6 != null
                            &&  lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6.Any(h=>h.contact != null)
                            ? lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6.Where(h=>h.contact != null).Select(h=>h.contact).Distinct() : null),
        Key1 = lev.basetable5 != null ? lev.basetable5.Id : null,
        Key2 = lev.basetable2 != null && lev.basetable2.basetable3 != null && lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable4 != null ?
                            lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable4.id      : null

    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

foreach (var x in tempResultSet)
{
    if (x.Contacts != null)
    {
        foreach (var contact in x.Contacts)
        {
            result.Add(new ResultModel
            {
                Key1 = x.Key1,
                Key2 = x.Key2,                           
                ContactKey = contact.id
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(new ResultModel
        {
            Key1 = x.Key1,
            Key2 = x.Key2                        
        });
    }
}

return result;
```

My Final Linq query is like

return _context.baseTable1.Where(h => h.id == Id ).Select(lev => new
{
Contact = (lev.baseTable2 != null
&& lev.baseTable2.baseTable3 != null
&& lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable5.Any(h => h.contact != null)
? lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable5.Where(h => h.contact != null).GroupBy(h => h.contact).Select(c=>c.FirstOrDefault().contact) : null),
Key1 = lev.office != null ? lev.office.id, : null,
Key2 = lev.baseTable2 != null && lev.baseTable2.baseTable3 != null && lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable4 != null ?
lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable4.id : null

```
        }).ToList().SelectMany(x =>
        {
            if (!x.Contact.Any())
            {
                return new List<FinalModel> { new FinalModel { Key1 = x.Key1, Key2 = x.Key2 } };
            }
            else
                return x.Contact.Select(contact => new FinalModel()
                {
                    ContactKey = contact.id,
                    Key1 = x.Key1,
                    Key2 = x.Key2
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) to flatten the array, e.g.:

```
List<ResultModel> result = _context.MainRecordTable.Where(h => h.id)
    .Select(lev => new 
    {
        Contacts = (lev.basetable2 != null 
                            && lev.basetable2.basetable3 != null 
                            && lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6 != null
                            &&  lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6.Any(h=>h.contact != null)
                            ? lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable6.Where(h=>h.contact != null).Select(h=>h.contact).Distinct() : null),
        Key1 = lev.basetable5 != null ? lev.basetable5.Id : null,
        Key2 = lev.basetable2 != null && lev.basetable2.basetable3 != null && lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable4 != null ?
                            lev.basetable2.basetable3.basetable4.id      : null

    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
    .SelectMany(x => {
      if (x.Contacts == null)
        return new ResultModel[]  
        {
          Key1 = x.Key1, 
          Key2 = x.Key2,
        };
      else 
        return x.Contacts.Select(contact => new ResultModel() 
          { 
            Key1 = x.Key1, 
            Key2 = x.Key2, 
            ContactKey = contact.id,
          }).ToArray();        
    })
    .ToList();
```

In the `SelectMany`, it is checked whether the contact list is set; if not, a single item is returned, otherwise, an item for each contact is returned.

Comment: I am getting some error as mentioned in other post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72900346/net-core-entity-framework-the-nested-query-is-not-supported-operation1-case

Answer (score 0):

I would find it more readable to create one `ResultModel` subcollection for the results *without* contact key and another subcollection for the results *with* a contact key. I suspect such an approach will also be easier to maintain over time than one single Linq expression.

You could first group the temporary results so that one subcollection contains **temporary results *without* contacts**, and the other subcollection contains **temporary results *with* contacts**.

Such a grouping is easily obtained by using [.ToLookup()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-6.0) with the appropriate condition for *contains contacts*:

```csharp
var tempResultByContainingContacts = tempResultSet
    .ToLookup(x => x.Contacts != null && x.Contacts.Any());
```

(I added the `&& x.Contacts.Any()` condition. If that does not suit your use case, you can leave it out.)

After defining the lookup table, you have:

- **temporary results *without* contacts** in `tempResultByContainingContacts[false]`
- **temporary results *with* contacts** in `tempResultByContainingContacts[true]`

Now, you can calculate one resulting subcollection based on the **temporary results *without* contacts**:

```csharp
var resultWithoutContactKey = tempResultByContainingContacts[false]
    .Select(x => new ResultModel
    {
        Key1 = x.Key1,
        Key2 = x.Key2
    });
```

as well as one resulting subcollection based on the **temporary results *with* contacts**:

```csharp
var resultWithContactKey = tempResultByContainingContacts[true]
    .SelectMany(x => x.Contacts
        .Select(contact => new ResultModel
        {
            Key1 = x.Key1,
            Key2 = x.Key2,
            ContactKey = contact.id
        }));
```

Lastly, the two resulting subcollections are concatenated to create `result`:

```csharp
var result = resultWithoutContactKey
    .Concat(resultWithContactKey)
    .ToList();
```

Note:

- By defining two subcollections and concatenating them, *the resulting order will be different from the original order*.
- Good naming conventions are important. I tried to select somewhat descriptive names, but have to admit, it was difficult especially for the lookup table. Hopefully you manage to find something more appropriate.

---

#### Suggestion after question update

I have not made any changes to the logic in your new, main `.Select()` block, except for adding one line to verify that `[...].baseTable5 != null`.

I would suggest splitting up the temporary subcollections and creating the resulting subcollections, following the pattern I have described above:

```
var tempResult = _context.baseTable1
    .Where(h => h.id == Id)
    .Select(lev => new 
    { 
        Contact = 
            lev.baseTable2 != null && 
            lev.baseTable2.baseTable3 != null && 
            lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable5 != null && // this line was added
            lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable5
                .Any(h => h.contact != null) 
            ? lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable5
                .Where(h => h.contact != null)
                .GroupBy(h => h.contact)
                .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault().contact) 
            : null, 
        Key1 =
            lev.office != null 
            ? lev.office.id, 
            : null, 
        Key2 =
            lev.baseTable2 != null && 
            lev.baseTable2.baseTable3 != null && 
            lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable4 != null 
            ? lev.baseTable2.baseTable3.baseTable4.id 
            : null
        })
    .ToList();

var tempResultByContainingContacts = tempResult
    .ToLookup(x => x.Contact != null && x.Contact.Any());
    
var resultWithoutContactKey = tempResultByContainingContacts[false]
    .Select(x => new FinalModel
    {
        Key1 = x.Key1,
        Key2 = x.Key2
    });

var resultWithContactKey = tempResultByContainingContacts[true]
    .SelectMany(x => x.Contact
        .Select(contact => new FinalModel
        {
            ContactKey = contact.id,
            Key1 = x.Key1,
            Key2 = x.Key2
        }));

var result = resultWithoutContactKey
    .Concat(resultWithContactKey)
    .ToList();

return result;
```

*If possible*, I would also suggest simplifying the new main `.Select()` block. I am not sure whether `?.` notation can be translated when querying the database, though. If it cannot, please ignore the following suggestion:

```csharp
var tempResult = _context.baseTable1
    .Where(h => h.id == Id)
    .Select(lev => new 
    { 
        Contact = lev.baseTable2?.baseTable3?.baseTable5?
            .Where(h => h.contact != null)
            .GroupBy(h => h.contact)
            .Select(c => c.FirstOrDefault().contact), 
        Key1 = lev.office?.id, 
        Key2 = lev.baseTable2?.baseTable3?.baseTable4?.id
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I was getting error on Distinct. that's wy use Groupby.Select(). Secondly I needed to send Final objects. Please see my Final linq in the edited Question

Comment: it could be great if you can write full solution here

Comment: @KamranShahid I am getting a little confused, seeing as the tables you are querying and the logic by which you are doing it has slightly changed. I have updated my answer, though, adding a new section that should reflect the changes. How does that work for you?